# Which is better, applying a displacement map to a mesh, or via a shader? Does it make a difference?

Tags: texturing, displacement

In [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zd4foATh8VY), two examples of applying a displacement map to a subdivided plane are given.

One creates a mesh that is visible in the 3D viewer and you can place objects on etc, and the other is applied via a shader.  Is the mesh version worse in any way?  Does it render less efficiently?

It seems more useful, apart from when you want to repeat texture tiles (is there a way to also achieve this using the mesh technique?)

Comment: The Displace modifier will displace the topology for real, you'll see the relief in Object or Material preview mode, not only Rendered mode, it will work in Eevee as well, you can apply the modifier if needed... So I guess it's more convenient. Maybe it needs more calculation than a Displacement node though, I don't know. In any case it's better to keep the mesh as low-poly as possible

Comment: As far as I can tell, the main reason for shader displacement is adaptive subdivision.  There was a point where I might have used it for procedural texturing capability in nodes, but I think geometry nodes is now a better way to do that.

Comment: So does adaptive subdivision not work when you only use the displace modifier, even if you set the camera and render settings correctly?